# How do I change the Services sub component to not use Safari web browser

Tags: safari, google-chrome, search, services

When I right click and use the "Search Google for" different things happen. For one, if I am in Chrome it opens a new tab in Chrome and searches as I want. However, if I use this menu anywhere else in macOS, it uses Safari.

The system itself has the Services sub-component listed under Keyboard preferences or under the Finder menus. The Services sub-component lists lots of right-click menu items but does not let me change them. It lists "Search Google for", but it does not allow any customization.

How can I change this menu? I don't want Safari to open when I search.

Comment: have you made Chrome your default browser? (Chrome > Preferences... > Default browser)

Comment: Yes, the default browser is set to Chrome and it works fine in most cases. Like if I right click within Slack or something it opens Chrome just fine. Only when I use certain apps (Outlook, Finder, etc.) it will open Safari instead.

Comment: Add PDF Preview to the list of problem apps that use Safari as the "Search with Google" right click menu.

Comment: Also note that the right click menu shows the Safari icon next to the menu choice. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to have been answered on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935301/how-to-force-mac-os-to-open-search-with-google-in-chrome) already and on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/369969/11306) even earlier.

The "search with google" entry is added by safari and therefore cannot be edited.  So the solution is to disable that one, create your own service using automator, and then assign the appropriate shortcut key that will take precedence over the built-in disabled one.  This is actually what I was going to suggest until I found that someone else had already gone through it.

I've copied/pasted answer from SO here.

Instructions:

1. Open Automator and choose Service as the type
2. Add a "Run Shell Script" action by dragging it to the right pane

[image: automator]

3. Add script

   open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"

   Adjust the TLD as needed for your country specific Google page. ex: http://www.google.co.in/search?q=

   A comment to the SO answer suggests - instead of "Run shell script" you can also use "Run javascript", use script `function run(input, parameters) { return "google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI(input) }`, and stack additional action "Internet > Open webpages" underneath. It could work faster. Also see [SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/1246656/11306)
4. Save the service as "Search Google"
5. Activate the service in System Preferences and optionally assign a keyboard shortcut. Once activated, "Search Google" will appear in the context menu

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: We should incorporate all of the relevant text from the link in case the other site deletes the question. It appears they feel it’s off topic and could delete the post and then we would lose access to the answer here.

Comment: I suspect the correct answer is also to replace step 3 by the JS answer in Super user. This needs testing first.

Comment: It would be better to make this as community wiki as it is a copy of other SO answers

Comment: I don't know how to do that.  You're welcome to do it or tell me how.

Comment: I mean. It doesn’t really matter to me as the bounty got an answer, but I’d rather give the points to a person than have them wiped out in a community wiki.

Comment: @Mark - shouldn't matter, I'd leave it as non-wiki so long as the source is referenced properly this is fine.

Comment: There's no need for community wiki in almost all situations these days. Hit us up on [meta] if anyone has questions. Awesome, awesome collaboration. Bringing the content from another site with care, curation and attribution should always be rewarded here with reputation and votes IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm under Ventura and things have slightly changed or moved around in macOS.

- in Automator there's no "Service" template so I chose "Quick action" which seems to be the equivalent. The wording is now "Workflow receives current" (instead of "Service receives selected"), don't forget to change this to "text" (default is "Automatic (Nothing)". There are a couple more options which I didn't touch.
- the System Settings have been completely revamped iOS-style, but there is a "Keyboard shortcuts" button in "Keyboard". In the window that opens up, the services are now categorized and the service I created appears under a "Text" category (the original appears under "Searching" if you want to disable it).